# Div taking up more space than it's supposed to at media 468 max pixels

Tags: html, css

zoomimg is set at   width: 145px; height: 145px; but it's pushing the text thats suppose to be in the it's parent out of the parent.

Zoomimg ProjectKort divs are the ones to look at

```
.projectkort{
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.zoomimg {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 1.0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It's live here -> [tsuts.tskoli.is/2t/2809984199/skapalon](http://tsuts.tskoli.is/2t/2809984199/skapalon)

Comment: What is the html inside projectkort? Is it a table, by chance?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2efa2145570c9f0db8a5b585740746ac

For some reason the I cant upload the html but heres a pic of it you can also visit tsuts.tskoli.is/2t/2809984199/skapalon and view the source.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'overflow:hidden' to your projectkort class ONLY for the smaller mobile breakpoint.

The content of the box are wider than the container - so they are overflowing. Once I added overflow:hidden to the parent projectkort class, the overflow on mobile went away.

Comment: Didnt seem to work for me, only thing that happened was that the text disappeared  and the zoomimg seems to be still taking upp 100vw.

Comment: At your first mobile breakpoint - add: overflow:hidden !important; to the projectkort class.

`@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
.projectkort {overflow:hidden !important; }
}`

Comment: Again, the text disappears but I need the text to be inside the projectkort parent for it work correctly, it just isn't and no one seems to figure out what to do. I've asked around 10 people to take a look no one can see to figure out whats happening.

Comment: If you go into chrome and inspect the page zoomimg is takeing upp the space that is pushing the text out and it's set at 140px width and still takes away all of the space inside projectkort. It may have something to do with the menu or col divs but nothing I do seems to fix it.